# Outlook 2016 RTF Format > Update Appointment body

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, rtf, outlook-2016

Working on a VSTO Add-In for Outlook, I need to generate, insert and replace text in an appointment body generated by Outlook 2016. Outlook encapsulate HTML tag into the RTF (MS-OXRTFEX) and I am looking for a library (free or licensed) or trick to manipulate text using this format. The text that I need to insert is in HTML or RTF format and I need to merge is with the appointment body.
Below is an example of the format:

```
{\*\htmltag50 <body lang=en-CH link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style='tab-interval:18.0pt'>}
{\*\htmltag96 <div class=WordSection1>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag64 <p class=MsoNormal style='mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag148 <span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;mso-ansi-language:#2000'>}\htmlrtf {\f4 \htmlrtf0 Hello world!
{\*\htmltag244 <o:p>}
{\*\htmltag252 </o:p>}
{\*\htmltag156 </span>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf0

{\*\htmltag72 </p>}
{\*\htmltag104 </div>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 
{\*\htmltag58 </body>}
```

Answer (score 3):

Outlook 2016 natively supports HTML on appointments, it is just OOM does not expose it. You can try to directly set the PR_HTML binary property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102`).

`Appointment.PropertyAcessor.SetProperty` might not let you set that property (it blocks some properties it considers "important"), but you can try in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and set the `RDOAppointmentItem.HTMLBody` property.

Also note that all stores natively supported by Outlook (OST, online Exchange, PST, IMAP, etc.) support HTML body, meaning that when an item is saved, the store provider updates all 3 body flavors (HTML, RTF, plain text) to keep them in sync.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, thanks for your feedback. Indeed, even reading the property gives me an unauthorised access exception :-/ I will try with Redemption :-)